# When can two electrons be excited in an atom?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, photon-emission, ionization-energy

In the National Institute of Standards and Technology's database, there is a table of the spectral lines produced by each atom in the periodic table

https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/heliumtable2_a.htm.

Each table includes a list of wavelengths produced by a singly ionized atom as well as a doubly ionized atom (except for hydrogen of course). Helium for example has a list of "He I" and "He II" spectral lines. Are the doubly ionized emission lines regularly encountered in the common spectral tube emission lamps you'd find in a high school chemistry lab? In my experience, I have not encountered one doubly ionized emission line with simple plastic diffraction grating spectrometers. Do these emissions require special circumstances (eg. extremely high energy densities or extremely low pressures) to form. Are the doubly ionized emission lines there but too faint to see?